# Old app headers into newer app version? [Jailbreak Tweak]

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, tweak

Sorry, for the confusing title. I am developing an iOS Tweak (for jailbreaks)
What I am trying to accomplish is something I haven't seen people do before but I am sure it is possible!

as an example lets say I am trying to change my username.

in app version 1.0 in the User.h there is a method called
- (void)setChangeUsername:(id)arg1;

which allows the change of usernames within the app, now on app version 1.2
the method is rendered useless / isnt there.
how could I reactivate this method so it allows the change of usernames?

would I have to edit the app binary, or import some old headers, not even sure what the first step of this process is, or if its even possible.

Sorry for the vague example but I hope it is enough information to get what I need answered!

If you would like more information I would be happy to write some more and be more detailed :)

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to bring back a feature/function that was available in a previous version of the app?

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do

Comment: If the function is still present within the binary, you'll just have to hook some other function and call `setChangeUsername` from there. If the symbols were stripped, finding the function might prove difficult and could require `memmem`'ing __TEXT.__text at runtime in order to find it. If the function isn't there at all anymore, you'll have to code it up yourself, which will require you to find the memory location where the pointer to the username is stored (assuming it was compiled as a global variable) or to hook a function that takes that pointer as an argument (if the variable is local).

Answer (score 0):

You can't call or hook a function that no longer exists. If you want to change the username you will have to find an alternative method to do so.